# Рисую текст в кастомном View с помощью Canvas. Как по клику на текст узнать оффсет определенного символа?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

У меня есть строка, которую я рисую с помощью Canvas определенным образом. Нужно, чтобы по клику на текст можно было распознать символ, на который был выполнен клик.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.